# Photobucket IOS integration

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, file-upload, photobucket

could anyone assist in authenticating to photobucket and uploading an image from and iPhone app? I am currently configured with many networks but I can't really find good documentation for the photobucket process. I guess the process is only authenticate and upload using customer key then username and password of the user?

Any help here would be amazing! Thanks in advance!

Jim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jim, the Photobucket (PB) process for authenticating is modified OAUTH. If you start looking at OAUTH examples you will find that you can authenticate on PB by simply converting a sample over to PB. e.g.: There's an OAuth starter kit set up for LinkedIN by Lee WHitney on Github courtesy of Kirsten Jones. Register an app with PB, get your keys and plug in the keys & correct PB URLs and you will be working. The URLS you need are:-

```
 requestTokenURLString = @"http://api.photobucket.com/login/request";
    accessTokenURLString = @"http://api.photobucket.com/login/access";
    userLoginURLString = @"http://photobucket.com/apilogin/login";
```

This will get you logged in but there's a lot more to come. PB have a code page and there is an Objective-C library including a modified OAUTH but it's missing docs so you need to work it out by studying the code. [Bitbucket Photobucket code for objective-c](https://bitbucket.org/photobucket/api-objc/overview)

The issue I have is to do with their usage of sub domains and trying to get OAUTH to work with that.

UPDATE: Solved: I have at last worked out how to get a part of the provided API working in my own Xcode project. Basically I added the special Oauth files which enable the requests to be set up correctly to get round the subdomain stuff. 
eg: OAuthASIHTTPRequest etc

I'm now getting full album info.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the follow up on this. Do you by chance have a sample code you could provide on how to auth / access the account?

Comment: The best starting point is the Photobucket api for iOS. This includes everything required to get photo bucket working. It's not the easiest integration, probably 3 times harder than flickr which has a fully working interface in iOS. Either study that code & get it working as is or do what I did & lift the files into your own project. My code is a huge jumble especially as I had to hack the PB code to get it working with Tumblr & Smugmug so it would confuse rather than assist.

Answer (score 1):

Official documentation for Photobucket API is available at: http://pic.pbsrc.com/dev_help/WebHelpPublic/PhotobucketPublicHelp.htm . You can find examples for login and media uploading.

Client libraries for Photobucket API are at: https://bitbucket.org/photobucket/api/wiki/Client_Libraries . There is a Objective-C one, like SundialSoft mentioned in answer.